# Hi I'm Rouzbeh Karimkhani, Help me lose body fat without working out

Tags: running

My question is what is the best way to lose belly fat without actually working out. I recently bought a gym membership maybe two months ago and I just have no motivation to work out. My name is Rouzbeh Karimkhani I reside in Toronto Ontario Canada. I own several businesses and just have no time for the gym.

Any advice regarding this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weight loss is as simple as calories in calories out. Eat less than your body needs to be at a certain weight with your movement level.

Basal metabolic rate (BMR) 2500 k/cal

Eat 2000k/cal a day, 7 days a week for 1 lb of fat loss.

Repeat with new weight.

I recommend checking a calorie calculator to find your BMR, and then use any calorie tracking app to keep up with daily intake.